# Javascript - What Prototype Property IS & difference between two coding styles that utilize it

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to grasp the Javascript prototype object ( or is it a property? ) and the principle behind prototypal programming.  And I'm having a rough go of it coming from straight OOP languages like Java, C#, and AS3.  I think it would help wrap my head around this if someone could explain to me the difference between these two snippets, both of which do basically the same thing - create a re-instantiable Ball 'class' ( is it really a class? ).

I have seen this:

```
Ball(radius, color) {
    if(radius == undefined) { radius = 40; }
    if(color == undefined) { color = "#ff0000"; }
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.scaleX  = 1;
    this.scaleY = 1;
    this.color = utils.parseColor(color);
    this.lineWidth = 1; 
    this.speed = 5;
    this.dx = 0;
    this.dy = 0;
    this.xunits = 0;
    this.yunits = 0;
    // Hokey properties
    this.angle = 0;
    this.radians = 0;

}

Ball.prototype.draw = function(context) {
    console.log("ball drawn");
    context.save();
    context.translate(this.x, this.y);
    context.rotate(this.rotation);
    context.scale(this.scaleX, this.scaleY);
    context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.beginPath();
    // x, y, radius, start angle, end_angle, anti-clockwise
    context.arc(0,0,this.radius, 0, (Math.PI * 2), true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    if(this.lineWidth > 0) {
        context.stroke();   
    }
    context.restore();
};
```

This came more intuitively to me but others have suggested I do something more like this:

```
 Ball = function(radius,color) {
        this.radius=radius;
        this.color=color;
    };
    Ball.prototype.x=0;
    Ball.prototype.y=0;
    Ball.prototype.speed=0;
    Ball.prototype.angle=0;
    Ball.prototype.dx=0;
    Ball.prototype.dy=0;
    Ball.prototype.radius=10;
    Ball.prototype.color="#000";
    Ball.prototype.draw=function() {

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = this.color; // line color
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    };
```

Please explain the main differences here to me.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I typically don't use prototype for variables unless you want them to be public. Otherwise I would define them within the constructor function.

Comment: If the property isn't affected by the constructor then add it via the constructor. There's not point iterating through each unaffected property on every constructor call. Also you can't have private or protected members in JS.

Comment: You can simulate public / private members by taking advantage of javascript's scoping rules, right?  I don't think I follow you about constructors -- in the examples above the constructor accepts radius and color arguments and sets them in accordance with the values received, right?  So wouldn't it work the other way around then -- if a property is affected by the constructor then and only then add it via the constructor?